# Typo3 - protect controller action with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, controller, action, typo3, extbase

Is there a way to password protect a specific controller (action) in typo3?
I want to provide a basic REST service consisting in a standard controller, but it shouldn't be accessible to everyone, but only to the ones who know the user/pass.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to TYPO3 Flow, Extbase doesn't include a Security Framework. Therefore by default every action  (that is in the list of actions for a plugin) is accessible for everyone by default.

You have several possibilities to restrict access on the TYPO3 side, but since I don't know how you're using your REST service and handling authentication (you should add more details to your question!) it's hard to pick the right one.

If the content is delivered by Fluid, you can use the Fluid security ViewHelpers that work like an if condition:

```
<f:security.ifHasRole [...]
<f:security.ifAuthenticated [...]
```

But most likely you aren't. In controller context, I suggest to add a user group check function to the controller and call it before executing the controller action:

```
/**
 * Checks if the current user is a certain group
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function checkUserHasPermission() {

    if (in_array($this->settings['allowedFeUserGroup'], $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->groupData['uid'])) {
        $this->userIsAdmin = TRUE;
    }

}
```

Then you add a group to the frontend users that are allowed and define it in your settings. If the user doesn't have permission, deny the access (and maybe redirect to a login).

Comment: I want this functionality for a single sign on integration with a second site. I used http authentication via curl. The session cookie is set on the same domain as the second site, so that it can read the session ID. Then, that site makes a request to a typo3 controller, passing the session ID, and then the controller decides if it's a valid session. If yes, the username is returned, so the user gets logged in on the second site (usernames are the same on both sites). I set in typo3's sys_registry table the api credentials (http user/pass) and check them against the ones received via curl.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use your specific controller url like

```
SetEnvIf Host "www\.your-link\.com/index.php?query" is_on_protected_site
Order deny,allow
Deny from env=is_on_protected_site
Satisfy any

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```